# How can I make scaffold only for controller and views if model already exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding, scaffold

I already have set up `Devise` to My App.
So User model is already generated, and exists by installing `Devise`

Now I'd like to add my own controller `users_controller.rb` and its views `index` and `show`.
How can I make scaffold without affecting to User model that already exists?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For scaffold with only 'name' column:

```
rails g scaffold User name --skip
```

Just add some columns.

Look to `rails g scaffold -h` output for additional information.

Comment: Thanks. What about the case that I'm not adding any column but I only want regular controller and regular views that'll be generated base on existing model.

Comment: You can input scaffold command manually (this way is faster if you have only one model to scaffold) or use script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644713/how-do-you-generate-the-form-for-an-existing-model-in-rails

Comment: @MKK you can generate scaffold for already created model e.g rails  g scaffold_controller Your_Model_Name

Answer (score 68):

Try this ,

```
rails g scaffold_controller controller_name
```

You will find more options via

```
rails generate -h
```

Comment: A sample output of scaffold_controller can be found at [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

Comment: I would use model name and its attributes instead, so it could add the model's attributes to the output files also, e.g., `rails g scaffold_controller User first_name:string last_name:string`

Answer (score 14):

If you want just controller and views without the whole scaffold you can do:

```
rails generate controller Users index show
```

Comment: What I want is scaffold without generating new columns and affection to existing model